# How to test iPhone PhoneGap app with custom plug-ins

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova

I have an Android application made by using PhoneGap, HTML5 and plug-ins (Java code). Now, I intend to hire a developer to code the plug-ins for iOS. However, I do not know how to test the app for iOS. I can find an iPhone, but don't want to purchase a new Mac for testing. What options do I have, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vsnomad.com/documentation/ you can try this but it costs money. You will need to create a key to sign the app also.